# Would content with low views and low social interaction negatively effect my current SEO?

Tags: seo, search-engines, ranking, content

I currently have a site with a few articles which are all decently ranked in google. I was thinking of adding lots of new content with a paid writer but I'm concerned a lot of the content may not get much attention, retweets, plus 1s etc where i don't have time to promote them.

Would this affect my sites SEO as a whole? And would it have any effect on the ranking of my current articles?

Answer (score 3):

This **not** "poor" content. Poor, or low quality content, would be:

- Content that is copied from other websites (duplicate content)
- Thin content (answers.com)
- Content that is written specifically for the search engines (landing pages)

Now your content may not get a lot of views which may make it difficult to get quality backlinks, but that would just make it more difficult to get those articles to rank well. But they certainly won't hurt your site or your current pages' rankings.